# Transition probability: Sudden approximation if the perturbation is large

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

I am trying to solve a problem where a system (a quantum harmonic oscillator) is suddenly perturbed by a large field of strength $E$. I want to calculate the transition probability for it to go from the ground state of the original Hamiltonian ($\frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2$) to the $n$th state of the new Hamilitonian ($\frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2$ - $qEx$).

If this were a small perturbation, then I would simply use first-order perturbation theory to calculate the transition probability.

**However, in my case, the perturbation is not small**. Therefore, first order approximations are not valid, and I would have to use the more general form given below:

[image]

My question is: Where does the perturbation effects (namely, $-qEx$ in the new Hamiltonian) come into play if I were to use Eq (10.73)? This seems like a far too general form, but I know that it is correct. Any suggestions on how I should approach this?

Comment: Rewrite $H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2 - qEx$ as
$$H= \frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 (x - \alpha)^2 + \beta$$
which is the shifted SHO and the solutions are known.

Comment: Thanks for the hint jim. Is there a reference you would suggest which deals with this in more detail?

Comment: I'm sure I've read it somewhere, but forget where. I tend to use Griffiths for QM but can't find it there. I'll check a few other likely suspects over the day or so and try and get back to you with the reference.

Comment: Sure I read it somewhere, sorry can't find the reference

Comment: It's in Griffiths, Problem 6.5

Comment: You can invoke eq. (10.73) iff you want to calculate the transition probability 'when the perturbation is just applied'. If not, then you need to use eq. (10.75) from that book. And in any event, you need to know the eigenstates of the new Hamiltonian $H = H_0 + H_p$, where the symbols have their usual meanings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the assumption that is being applied is that the underlying wavefunction $$|\Psi\rangle = \sum_n \alpha_n e^{-iE_nt/\hbar} |\psi_n\rangle,$$ is not going to change in the time it takes the Hamiltonian to change. (Let's assume $t=0$ when the Hamiltonian changes for simplicity.)

Therefore we should find a new basis $|\phi_n\rangle$ for the new Hamiltonian $\hat H$ and then re-expand $|\Psi\rangle$ in terms of the new basis. Since it is an orthonormal basis, $$\hat 1 = \sum_m |\phi_m\rangle\langle \phi_m|,$$and therefore we have $$|\Psi\rangle = \hat 1|\Psi\rangle = \sum_{mn}\alpha_n\langle\phi_m|\psi_n\rangle~|\phi_m\rangle.$$Your expression comes when $\alpha_n = \{1 \text{ if } n=k\text{ else } 0\}$, in which case we can simplify that sum to only $$|\psi_k\rangle = \sum_m \langle \phi_m|\psi_k\rangle ~|\phi_m\rangle.$$We see that the probability of being in the state $|\phi_\ell\rangle$ is $\big|\langle \phi_\ell|\psi_k\rangle\big|^2,$ as promised.

Observing as @jim says that the two harmonic oscillator solutions are shifted versions of each other in position space, this integral (before being squared) is $$\langle \phi_m|\psi_0\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx~\psi_m^*(x - \lambda)~\psi_0(x),$$ and you can hypothetically just plug in those functions and evaluate that integral.

There may also be a more theoretical way to your solution by looking at the eigenstates of the usual bosonic annihilator (sometimes called a "ladder operator") $\hat a = \sqrt{m\omega\over2\hbar}\left(\hat x + \frac{i}{m\omega} \hat p\right)$  of the harmonic oscillator. These eigenstates look like $\hat a|\alpha = \alpha |\alpha\rangle$ and generally look like copies of the vacuum state shifted in their phase space to the position $x = \sqrt{2\hbar\over m\omega}~\Re \alpha$, $p = \sqrt{2\hbar m\omega} ~\Im \alpha,$ if I'm remembering all of the constants correctly.

Since $a |n\rangle = \sqrt{n} |n-1\rangle$ we can obtain a series expansion of $|\alpha\rangle = \sum_n c_n|\alpha\rangle$ where the equation $\hat a |\alpha\rangle = \alpha |\alpha\rangle$ becomes the expression $$c_n = \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt n} c_{n-1}.$$Solving we have $c_n = Z \alpha^n/\sqrt{n!}$ for some normalization constant $Z$ which must force $Z^2 \sum_n |\alpha|^{2n} / n! = 1$ and therefore $Z=\exp\big(-\frac12 |\alpha|^2\big).$

If all of that is correct then your transition probability will be something of the form $$\big|\langle \phi_k|\psi_0\rangle\big|^2 = \frac1{k!}~\exp\left(-\frac{m\omega \lambda^2}{2\hbar}\right)~\left(\frac{m\omega \lambda^2}{2\hbar}\right)^k.$$